# How do a slow recursive delete on Linux?

Tags: linux

I have some directories on our production servers which I want to delete. However last time I deleted them they caused connections to the servers to start timing out as the disk IO was being swamped. Is there a command I can use to slowly delete these directories or should I write myself a shell script with some liberal sleeps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `sleep` on your system returns 0 then you can just stick it in a `find` command:

```
find ... -exec sleep 1 \; -delete
```

Comment: I thought about that but there are enough files that it would take at least a day at that speed.

Comment: GNU `sleep` can take fractional delays, i.e. `sleep 0.05`.

Comment: You know that makes complete sense and I don't know why I assumed it didn't handle fractions! I'll blame it on Monday morning. Thanks.

Comment: The command I used `find . -depth -delete -print -exec sleep 0.05 \;`

Answer (score 2):

Here is alternative

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -n 5 -0 -I {} rm {}; sleep 10`

change parameters

`-n 5` # this is how many files at the same time will be passed to rm command.

and

`sleep 10` # this is how long in seconds will command sleep before next rm chunk is executed

Answer (score 0):

How about:

ls  | xargs -I {} -n 1 sh -c 'echo {} ; sleep 1'

Just replace echo with rm and you should be good.